# Using list comprehension to get count of all files in multiple sub directories

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a folder which contains multiple sub directories, each of those containing several files. I would like to get the sum total of all files in all sub directories. The following list comprehension works quite well:

```
sum_total = len([file for file in os.listdir(current_directory)])
```

How would I modify this to include counting all files in all sub directories (not just the current_directory)? Or do I have to use a traditional for loop and counter? Is there something similar to the following that I could use?

```
sum_total = len([file in os.listdir(current_directory + '\\' + folder) for folder in os.listdir(current_directory)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) will recurse through all subdirectories:

```
import os
total = sum(len(files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'))
```

Note that this counts only files, not the names of any subdirectories.
This is different than the code you posted.

```
len([file for file in os.listdir(current_directory)])
```

counts both files and the name of (toplevel) subdirectories.

---

By the way, although you asked for a list comprehension, I suggest a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
(len(files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'))
```

There is no significant difference in speed (at least for moderate-sized directories) but the generator expression uses less memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about difference b/w counting file/folder. Good to know :)